# How to correctly submit angular form?

Tags: typescript, crud, angular-forms

I created a form to submit some data to the backend, but when I click on the submit button, nothing happens, here is my code   :

```
app.component.html :
<form[formGroup]="plcService.form" class="normal-form"
(Submit) = "onSubmit()" >
<mat-grid - list cols = "2" rowHeight = "600px" >
<mat-grid - tile >
<div class="controles-container" >
  <input type="hidden" formControlName = "$key" />
    <mat-form - field >
    <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder = "Name" />
      </mat-form-field>
      < mat - form - field >
      <input formControlName="age" matInput placeholder = "Age" />
        </mat-form-field>
        < mat - form - field >
        <input formControlName="email" matInput placeholder = "Email" />
          </mat-form-field>
          < div class="button-row" >
            <button mat - raised - button color = "primary" type = 
  "submit"
              (click) = "onSubmit()" >
              Save
              < /button>
              < button mat - raised - button color = "warn"(click) = 
   "onClear()" >
                Clear form
                  < /button>
                  < /div>
                  < /div>
                  < /mat-grid-tile>
                  < /mat-grid-list>
                  < /form>


  app.compenent.ts :
  onSubmit() {
  this.systemService.addSystem(this.system);
  }

  systemService.ts :

  addSystem(system: System): Observable < System > {
  return this.http.post<System>(this.endpoint, system, httpOptions).pipe(
  tap((system: System) =>
  console.log(`Created or updated system w/ id=${system.name}`)
  ),
  catchError(this.handleError<System>('addSystem'))
  );
  }

system.model :

export class System {
public name: string;
public age: string;
public email: string;
}
```

When I submit the form , in the console I get [Object Object] and not the JSON  object of type System . any ideas ?

Comment: It's ngSubmit, not Submit. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#saving-form-data. And your button shouldn't have a (click).

Comment: no , unfortunately that's not the problem. I tried modfying the code but it didn't work

Comment: There are plenty of other problems with the submitted code, which isn't valid HTML. If you want help, post a complete **minimal** example reproducing the problem, as a stackblitz.

Comment: it's a little complicated to recreate the same example . what's wrong with the HTML I posted please ?

Comment: `<mat-form - field >`: why are there spaces inside the tag name? `< /button>`: why is there a space between the bracket and the /? Why is your clear button a submit button? My guess is that "it doesn't work" means "no request is sent to the server". That's expected, since you never subscribe to the observable.

Comment: @JBNizet yes , I'm not able to send the request to the backend . the problem is the addSystem() method ? how can I fix it please ?

Comment: the HTML tags are correct in my code , it's just the formatting here that is not correctly done

Comment: I answered the question already: you must subscribe to the observable returned by the service. Nothing happens if you don't subscribe. https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data